# How to reset TempData in a specific condition but can use it in one method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I have multiple Checkboxes in a view and on true or false i am querying with database to get the records of selected Category and than export those records in excel.

I have multiple ActionMethods in  my project and I am using **Tempdata** to hold the selected categories from the user. Like i have to pass those categories in a method where i am exporting records in excel so for that reason I am using **Tempdata**.

Here is my view.

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchCustomReport", "PassengerInfo", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6 checkbox">
                            <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Business, new { @class = "big-checkbox" }) Business</label>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Gold, new { @class = "big-checkbox" }) Gold</label>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Platinium, new { @class = "big-checkbox" }) Platinium</label>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Guest, new { @class = "big-checkbox" }) Guest</label>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Paid, new { @class = "big-checkbox"}) Paid</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                            <label>From</label>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", id = "number", required = "required", placeholder = "From" } })
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                            <label>To</label>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", id = "number2", required = "required", placeholder = "To" } })
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input style="float: right ; background-color:white; color:#e60053 " type="Submit" class="btn" value="Generate Report" onmouseover=" this.style.backgroundColor = '#e60053', this.style.color = 'white' " onmouseout="    this.style.backgroundColor = 'white',   this.style.color = '#e60053'">
                        </div>
                    }
```

Here it is my method of this view.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchCustomReport(CustomReport record)
    {
        if (!General.ValidateSession())
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
        }
        if (record.Date1 == null || record.Date2 == null)
        {
            return View("invaliddatesinput");
        }

        if (record.Date1.Length< 10 ||record.Date2.Length > 10)
        {
            return View("invaliddatesinput");
        }

        if (record.Business == true)
        {
            TempData["Business"] = 1;
        }
        if (record.Gold == true)
        {
            TempData["Gold"] = 2;
        }
        if (record.Platinium == true)
        {
            TempData["Platinium"] = 3;
        }
        if (record.Guest == true)
        {
            TempData["Guests"] = 4;
        }
        if (record.Paid == true)
        {
            TempData["Paid"] = 5;
        }
        TempData["FromDate"] = record.Date1;
        TempData["toDate"] = record.Date2;

        return RedirectToAction("CustomReport");
    }
```

I am holding selected categories and using it in different function.

```
  public PassengerPaging GetCustomReport(int skipParam)
    {
        string frDate = TempData["FromDate"].ToString();
        string toDate = TempData["toDate"].ToString();

        int bus = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Business"]);
        int gold = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Gold"]);
        int plat = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Platinium"]);
        int guest = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Guests"]);
        int Paid = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Paid"]);
        TempData.Keep();
        PassengerPaging psngr = new PassengerPaging();
        psngr.Passengers = repository.GetCustomReport(bus, gold, plat, guest, Paid, frDate, toDate , skipParam).Select(x => new ViewModel.Passenger
        {

            ID = x.ID,
            Name = x.Name,
            FlightNo = FlightRepos.SelectByID(x.FlightId).Airline.AirlineCode + FlightRepos.SelectByID(x.FlightId).FlightNo,
            Airline = FlightRepos.SelectByID(x.FlightId).Airline.Name,
            SeatNo = x.SeatNo,
            SequenceNo = x.SequenceNo,
            Date = x.Date,
            CheckinTime = x.CheckinTime,
            CheckoutTime = x.CheckoutTime,
            Category = categoryrepos.SelectByID(x.CategoryID).CategoryCode,
            RefSeatNo = x.RefSeatNo,
            isGuest = x.isGuest,
            NoOfGuest = x.NoOfGuests,
            Cash = x.Cash,
            CreditCard = x.CreditCard,
            EntryBy = x.EnterBy
        }).ToList();
        psngr.skip = skipParam;
        if (psngr.Passengers.Count() > 0)
        {
            psngr.Count = repository.GetCustomReportForCount(bus, gold, plat, guest, Paid, frDate, toDate).Count() - skipParam;
        }
        return psngr;
    }
```

I have a button in the view of above method in which user can export data in excel.

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"> <a style="background-color:white" onmouseover=" this.style.backgroundColor = '#3597db', this.style.color = 'white'" onmouseout=" this.style.color='#3597db' ,this.style.backgroundColor = 'white'" class="btn " onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ExportToExcelCustom", "PassengerInfo")'">Export Detail Data</a> </div>
```

Here it is my exporting method.

```
 public IEnumerable<AllExcelRecords> GetListCustom()
    {
        int bus = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Business"]);
        int gold = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Gold"]);
        int plat = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Platinium"]);
        int guest = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Guests"]);
        int Paid = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Paid"]);
        string frDate = TempData["FromDate"].ToString();
        string toDate = TempData["toDate"].ToString();
        var result = repository.ExcelBydateCustom(bus, gold, plat, guest, Paid, frDate, toDate).Select(x => new ViewModel.AllExcelRecords
        {
            ID = x.ID,
            Name = x.Name,
            FlightNo = FlightRepos.SelectByID(x.FlightId).FlightNo,
            Airline = FlightRepos.SelectByID(x.FlightId).Airline.Name,
            SeatNo = x.SeatNo,
            SequenceNo = x.SequenceNo,
            Date = x.Date,
            CheckinTime = x.CheckinTime,
            CheckoutTime = x.CheckoutTime,
            Remarks = x.Remarks,
            EntryBy = x.EnterBy,
            Category = categoryrepos.SelectByID(x.CategoryID).CategoryCode,
            NoOfGuests = x.NoOfGuests,
            RefSeatNo = x.RefSeatNo,
            withGuests = x.isGuest,
            Cash = x.Cash,
            CreditCard = x.CreditCard
        }).ToList();
        return result;
    }
    public ActionResult ExportToExcelCustom()
    {
        if (!General.ValidateSession())
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
        }
        string fDate = TempData["FromDate"].ToString();
        string tDate = TempData["toDate"].ToString();
        var grdview = new GridView();
        grdview.DataSource = this.GetListCustom();
        grdview.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= Customize Report " + fDate + " - " + tDate + ".xls ");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);
        htmlWriter.Write("<table><tr><td colspan='13' align='center'><font size='45'>Customize Report</font></td></tr></table>");
        grdview.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        Response.Output.Write(strWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
        return RedirectToAction("DateRecords");
    }
```

Problem : 
It is working fine but  there is an issue i am facing.

Let say user select business and gold category and get the job done he got 12 records of that specific category because DB have 12 records of that two categories.

Now user went back and select Platinium category only and DB have 6 records of that single category so user should get 6 records but it is getting 12 + 6 = 18 records. because in TempData gold and business category is present.

to overcome this , i removed that line Tempdata.keep but after this I can't export the data in excell it is throwing null exception.

Comment: Before change catagory make all tempvalue null except desire tempvalue.

Comment: not getting your point

Answer (score 4):

As I understood your requirement,you have to clear Tempdata before filling data.
like initialize Tempdata with null value before adding data in method

```
TempData["Platinium"] = null;
```

So this will clear old data and add new data in TempData.

Thank you